# Method with object as a parameter and it returns the type i want in C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, generics

I made this method for my application in C# (.NET 4.0). 
This method converts the object you pass as a parameter to the type T. I would like to share it and ask if there are better solutions for this.

```
   public static T ReturnMeThis<T>(object variable) {
            T dataOut = default(T);
            try {
                if(Convert.IsDBNull(variable) && typeof(T) == typeof(String))
                    dataOut = (T)(object)"";
                else if(!Convert.IsDBNull(variable))
                    dataOut = (T)Convert.ChangeType(variable, typeof(T));
                return dataOut;
            }
            catch(InvalidCastException castEx) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Invalid cast in ReturnMeThis<" + typeof(T).Name + ">(" + variable.GetType().Name + "): " + castEx.Message);
                return dataOut;
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error in ReturnMeThis<" + typeof(T).Name + ">(" + variable.GetType().Name + "): " + ex.Message);
                return dataOut;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the object?

```
TypeIWant t = variable as TypeIWant;

if(t != null)
{
// Use t
}
```

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

As tomasmcguinness said, the as keyword would work fine.  It will return null on invalid casts w/o throwing an error.  If you want to have a dedicated method that logged invalid casts, you could do something like this:

```
public static T ReturnMeThis<T>(object variable) where T : class
{
    T dataOut = variable as T;
    if (dataOut == null)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Cannot cast {0} as a {1}", variable.GetType().Name, dataOut.GetType().Name));

    return dataOut;
}
```

Comment: The thing is that the method I made can't return null.